# pascal triangle starting and ending with 1

Tags: java

Pasted below is a program to print Pascal's triangle. The way to compute any given position's value is to add up the numbers to the position's right and left in the preceding row. For instance, to compute the middle number in the third row, you add 1 and 1. the sides of the triangle are always 1 because you only add the number to the upper left or the upper right (there being no second number on the other side).

```
     int pascal[][]=new int[50][50]; int j;
     for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
     {
         pascal[i][i]=1;
         for(j=1;j<i;j++)
         {
             pascal[i][j]=pascal[i-1][j-1]+pascal[i-1][j];
         }

         for(int n=1;n<=m-i;n++)
         {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }

         for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
         {
             System.out.print(pascal[i][k]);
             System.out.print(" ");
         }

         System.out.println(" ");
     }
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without using arrays?

I'm trying this combination without arrays:

```
                                                1
                                           1        1
                                       1        2        1
                                   1       3        3        1
                              1       4        6        4        1
                         1        5      10      10       5        1
```

Comment: there is any way to do the same without using array??

Comment: "I want this combination," leads the reader to believe that you need only that specific result. Are you sure that's what you want? You can actually code for that specific result, or more generally. If you were adding an example, please make that change.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily compute it using [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

[image: Here's an image showing that approach visually]

You can compute combination as:

```
|n| = (n!) / ((n-k)!*k!)   
|k|
```

So if you want to print the image above you would start as:

```
int size = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

   for(int k = 0; k < (size - i)/2; k++) 
       System.out.print(" "); // print the intendation

   for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){

       System.out.print(combination(i,j));
   }

   System.out.println("");
}
```